# How to create a matrix(using vector stl) from console in c++? (i.e. without knowing the size of the matrix)

Tags: c++, matrix, stl

I am working on a code that creates a matrix class, using a STL vector. I want the user input (on console) as:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

or

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Just that and nothing else. i.e. the code should be able to get the number of rows and columns from the input itself (instead of explicitly asking user).

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Do share what you have tried so far please.

Comment: Just curious, why negative votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. I found a way to do it. Thanks Andrei..
Here is how i did it..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


int main() {
        vector <vector <double> > v;
        string s;
        int count=0, ncol=0,check=0,nrow=0;
        while(1) {
                getline(cin,s);
                if (s.length() == 0)
                        break;
                for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                        if (s[i]==' ')
                                count++;
                count++;
                if (check==0) {
                        check++;
                        ncol=count;
                }
                if (count != ncol) {
                        cout << "ncol should be same in each row!" <<endl;
                        break;
                }
                v.resize(nrow+1);
                istringstream buf(s);
                istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;
                vector<string> dummy(beg, end);
                for (int i=0; i<ncol;i++) 
                        v[nrow].push_back(stod(dummy[i]));
                nrow++;
                count=0;
        }
        //print the vector 'v' here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read input lines one at a time, until a line is empty.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string s,s1;
  do{
    getline (std::cin, s);
    s1+=s;
  }while(s.length()>0);
 cout<<s1;
 return 0;
}
```

Instead of adding to s1, you would need to write a simple function to split the string s into numbers, store the number of columns at the first step, test if the number of columns change (throw an error), increment the number of rows at every step, and of course, store the elements of the matrix in a vector. Once you are done, you can construct the matrix

Comment: Thanks. I thought that way only. But was wondering if there's even more easier way.